# Deploying ad-hoc apps on ipad without knowing the clients UDID

Tags: ios, ipad, deployment, certificate, enterprise

I'm developing an exclusive app for my clients. This app will be distributed to them specifically, they don't want to have it uploaded on the app store. The problem is: when packing up the app into an .ipa file, I need to specify the UDIDs of the devices that will be able to run this app. But trying to pry them out of my clients is too inconvinient and, frankly, practically impossible.

Originally, I thought this to be impossible because of the apple's strict safety policy, but we've found out it's possible to do somehow if you have an Enterprise account, which we do. You can somehow make it work by installing the .mobileprovision file along with the .ipa on an arbitrary device and make it work. We've seen our competition do it like this:

http://www.devicepharm.com/2011/08/how-to-install-enterprise-applications-on-the-ipad/

What kind of certificates/mobileprovisions must I create to make this work? How do I make my app distribuable like this?

Comment: If you have a enterprise account you should create a InHouse profile and sign the with this profile. This will allow you to install the IPA without knowing the UDID.

Comment: An enterprise application can only be built with an enterprise apple developer account. There is quite a lot about this on the apple developer portal as well as hundreds of tutorials. Do a little research

Comment: We have an enterprise apple developer account. I've been researching this for two days stright now and I still can't make it work (this doesn't prove anything, I might just be demented).
If there are hundreds of tutorials on this topic then that is great news! Somehow I've managed to miss them in the past days. Could you please point me to some of them?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Beta by Fabric to distribute your builds. You just need to obtain their email ids to which you invite them to Beta. Once they accept the invitation on their mobile device. Any missing UDIDs will be shown up when you try to send a build to those email ids through the fabric plugin which you can include in your adhoc provisioning profile. Also, another thing to note it that once the client has accepted the invite you can see his device and its UDID in the web login of Fabric itself to use in adding it as a device in your developer portal/Provisioning profile.

You can find more info here.
https://dev.twitter.com/crashlytics/beta-distribution

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind
I was building the app in flash and the problem was ultimately with something different linked with that.
Indeed there are many tutorials on this topic and they were correct.